# Inner Join com like, Mysql e Datatable

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, operador-like

Fala pessoal, estou com um problema na hora de pesquisa um campo no datatable,
eu tenho uma tabela de contribuintes, essa está vinculada com a contribuintes_param, contribuintes_end e contribuintes_tel. Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa usando like e inner join, até então a pesquisa por nome, tipo_param, cep e rua, está funcionando perfeitamente... agora, o tipo_tel e fone_tel está se repetindo!!!!!

```
SELECT  n_contribuintes.id_cont, n_contribuintes.nome_cont, n_contribuintes_param.tipo_param,
    n_contribuintes_end.cep_end, n_contribuintes_end.rua_end, n_contribuintes_tel.tipo_tel, 
    n_contribuintes_tel.fone_tel FROM n_contribuintes 
    INNER JOIN n_contribuintes_param ON n_contribuintes.id_cont = n_contribuintes_param.id_cont_param  
    INNER JOIN n_contribuintes_end ON n_contribuintes.id_cont = n_contribuintes_end.id_cont_end  
    INNER JOIN n_contribuintes_tel ON n_contribuintes.id_cont = n_contribuintes_tel.id_cont_tel
            AND nome_cont LIKE '%avulso%' 
            OR tipo_param LIKE '%avulso%' 
            OR cep_end LIKE '%avulso%'
            OR rua_end LIKE '%avulso%'
            OR tipo_tel LIKE '%avulso%'
            OR fone_tel LIKE '%avulso%'
            WHERE id_esc_cont = 30
            GROUP BY id_cont
```

Testes:::

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srqDt.jpg)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKUAM.jpg)

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65QwT.jpg)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O `INNER JOIN` repete as linhas pra cada ocorrência, no seu caso de telefone e endereço. Você quer mostrar só 1?

Comment: inclua as imagens na pergunta, muitos hosts são bloqueados e muitas pessoas podem não ver, além de ficar mais claro

Comment: @Sorack sim, só o que eu pesquisa, mas ele repete todos...

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu tentei, mais não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separe as responsabilidades da sua `query`. Deixe no `ON` apenas o vínculo das tabelas:

```
SELECT n_contribuintes.id_cont,
       n_contribuintes.nome_cont,
       n_contribuintes_param.tipo_param,
       n_contribuintes_end.cep_end,
       n_contribuintes_end.rua_end,
       n_contribuintes_tel.tipo_tel,
       n_contribuintes_tel.fone_tel 
  FROM n_contribuintes 
       INNER JOIN n_contribuintes_param ON n_contribuintes.id_cont = n_contribuintes_param.id_cont_param 
       INNER JOIN n_contribuintes_end ON n_contribuintes.id_cont = n_contribuintes_end.id_cont_end 
       INNER JOIN n_contribuintes_tel ON n_contribuintes.id_cont = n_contribuintes_tel.id_cont_tel 
 WHERE id_esc_cont = 30
  AND (nome_cont LIKE '%avulso%'
    OR tipo_param LIKE '%avulso%'
    OR cep_end LIKE '%avulso%'
    OR rua_end LIKE '%avulso%'
    OR tipo_tel LIKE '%avulso%'
    OR fone_tel LIKE '%avulso%')
 GROUP BY id_cont
```

Comment: Legal!!! funcionou, estava usando dessa forma... AND nome_cont LIKE '%%' AND n_contribuintes.id_esc_cont = 30
    OR tipo_param LIKE '%%' AND n_contribuintes.id_esc_cont = 30
    OR cep_end LIKE '%%' AND n_contribuintes.id_esc_cont = 30
    OR rua_end LIKE '%%' AND n_contribuintes.id_esc_cont = 30
    OR tipo_tel LIKE '%%' AND n_contribuintes.id_esc_cont = 30
    OR fone_tel LIKE '%%' AND n_contribuintes.id_esc_cont = 30, e também funcionou, mas a sua é mais limpa kkk, obrigado!